# how to reconstruct scene from different views' point clouds

Tags: kinect, point-clouds, 3d-reconstruction

I am facing a problem on 3D reconstruction since I am a new to this filed. I have some different views' depth map(point clouds), I want to use them to reconstruct the scene to get the effect like using the kinect fusion. Is there any paper of source code to settle this problem. Or any ideas on this problem.
PS:the point cloud is stored as a file with (x,y,z), you can check [here](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1miNVPnq) to get the data.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated that you are new to this field, I shall attempt to keep this high level. Please do comment if there is something that is not clear.

The pipeline you refer to has three key stages:

- Integration
- Rendering
- Pose Estimation

The Integration stage takes the [unprojected points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix) from a Depth Map (Kinect image) under the current pose and "integrates" them into a spatial data structure (a Voxel Volume such as a [Signed Distance Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function) or a hierarchical structure like an [Octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree)), often by maintaining per Voxel running averages.

The Rendering stage takes the inverse pose for the current frame and produces an image of the visible parts of the model currently in view. For the common volumetric representations this is achieved by [Raycasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting). The output of this stage provides the points of the model to which the next live frame is registered (the next stage).

The Pose Estimation stage registers the previously extracted model points to those of the live frame. This is commonly achieved by the [Iterative Closest Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) algorithm.

With regards to pertinent literature, I would advise the following papers as a starting point.

[KinectFusion: Real-Time Dense Surface Mapping and Tracking](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ismar2011.pdf)

[Real-time 3D Reconstruction at Scale using Voxel Hashing](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~niessner/papers/2013/4hashing/niessner2013hashing.pdf)

[Very High Frame Rate Volumetric Integration of Depth Images on
Mobile Devices](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evictor/infinitam/files/ismar15infinitam.pdf)